# Ignore XML Validation for JAX-WS clients

Tags: java, xml, jax-ws

I've got a few JAX-WS services I'm trying to consume, but the XML being returned from the service (of which I cannot change) has an invalid DTD (producing the XMLStreamReaderException as there are no white spaces between `publicId` and `systemId`). How do I make the clients ignore poorly-formed DTDs?

Comment: what version of jaxws are you using?  i didn't know jaxws dealt in dtds.

Comment: [this link](http://metro.1045641.n5.nabble.com/JAX-WS-RI-2-1-x-susceptible-to-DTD-entity-expansion-attack-td1062920.html) might be useful.  details dtd handling as it relates to various jaxws versions.

Comment: Very generally, I'd look at making the WS use a local DTD (don't know if this is a JAX feature), or put in a custom handler: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftwbs_jaxwshandler.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the invalid `DTD` part of a `WSDL`? if yes, you could use `JAXWS catalog` to read the `XML` locally and then just invoke the service.

You need to download the `WSDL`, fix it and store it locally. Then, when creating a `Service` instance read the `WSDL` from your local store. Update the `endpoint` property and invoke the service.

Comment: This was what needed to be done, sadly. I feel like it's a shame that JAX can't just handle DTDs with such a minor problem, especially when it knows _exactly_ what's wrong and is fine with an empty string value.